# how to find sdk and xcode version number from .framework or .a file

Tags: ios, iphone, xcode, frameworks, static-libraries

I have a .framework file and .a taken from two different projects. i want to find out the version number of the sdk used and also xcode version from the .a and .framework files.

is there a way to figure that out ?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

For a `.framework file` , you can get Xcode version

```
plutil -p YOUR-FRAMWORK-PATH-NAME.framework/Info.plist | grep DTXcodeBuild
```

you will get the output something like:

```
"DTXcodeBuild" => "9C40b"
```

`9C40b` stands for Xcode9.2

[image]

Comment: That solution seem to be outdated. Any update?

Comment: @MartinMlostek for me it works as expected. Note: if you use .xcframework, it slightly differs:

plutil -p /[path-to-xcframwork]/[ABC].xcframework/[build]/[ABC].framework/Info.plist | grep DTXcodeBuild

output e.g.: "DTXcodeBuild" => "13F100"

Answer (score 1):

I was also looking for the version of a particular framework. I was able to locate it within the Framework's Info.plist file.

1. Right click the Framework in the Project Navigator, then "Open in Finder"
2. Within the YourFramework.xcframework directory, find the nested YourFramework.framework directory (for reference, mine was nested under "ios-arm64")
3. Within the .framework directory, find the Info.plist file and open it.
4. The version should be listed under the key "Bundle version string (short)"

[image: Screenshot of Framework's Info.plist]

The accepted solution didn't work for me at the time of this writing, so I'd figure I'd share for anyone coming in after me.

Answer (score -4):

For xcode version click xcode>about xcode.

[image]

For the framework just open a header file from that framework, usually in the comments on top the version is mentioned.

Comment: i am making sure my question is clear, please check.

Comment: Actually for a lib file (.a) there is no way to determine the version.